# OS X Lion SSH server error

Tags: macos, ssh, sshd

when trying to ssh into my macbook after changing the ssh port and disabling password authentication, I'm getting this error:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

I've found a lot of information on that error and how people are fixing it on linux servers, but those solutions don't work for me.

Has anyone worked around this issue?